# SQL: sp_validatelogins then drop orphaned by single query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm quite new to t-sql and I wrote this query to identify and then drop logins that no longer exist in active directory. I have to say that somehow it works and I get the result but I feel that there is a way to do better. Is there anyone who can put me in the right direction?
Thank you!

```
    -- delete temp tables if exist
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#TMP_SP_VALIDATELOGINS') IS NOT NULL BEGIN
    DROP TABLE #TMP_SP_VALIDATELOGINS
END

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#mytemp') IS NOT NULL BEGIN
    DROP TABLE #mytemp
END

-- find invalid logins and put them into temp table
CREATE TABLE #TMP_SP_VALIDATELOGINS
    (
        COL_SID varbinary(85) NOT NULL
        , COL_NT_Login SYSNAME NOT NULL
    )

INSERT INTO #TMP_SP_VALIDATELOGINS
EXEC sp_validatelogins

-- add column for rowcount 
set rowcount 0
select NULL mykey, * into #mytemp from #TMP_SP_VALIDATELOGINS

set rowcount 1
update #mytemp set mykey = 1

DECLARE @login NVARCHAR(MAX)

while @@rowcount > 0
begin
    set rowcount 0

    -- select name to drop
    set @login = (select COL_NT_Login from #mytemp where mykey = 1)

    declare @drop varchar(200)
    set @drop =  (select 'drop login [' + name + '];'
    from sys.server_principals 
    WHERE name = @login )
    exec (@drop)

    delete #mytemp where mykey = 1
    set rowcount 1
    update #mytemp set mykey = 1

end
set rowcount 0

DROP TABLE #mytemp
DROP TABLE #TMP_SP_VALIDATELOGINS
GO
```

Comment: `better` in what ways ?

Comment: @Squirrel ... better ... with more elegant code, maybe without create temp tables

Comment: If you use `sp_helptext` to get the definition, you'll see that all this sproc does is grab the results of `select 'SID' = sid, 'NT Login' = loginname from master.dbo.syslogins where isntname = 1 and get_sid(loginname) is null`. This is easily incorporated directly into a query (if you replace the internal `get_sid` function with the public `suser_sid` function).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
CREATE TABLE #TMP_SP_VALIDATELOGINS
    (
        COL_SID varbinary(85) NOT NULL
        , COL_NT_Login SYSNAME NOT NULL
    )

INSERT INTO #TMP_SP_VALIDATELOGINS
EXEC sp_validatelogins


-- the trick is to concatenate the `DROP LOGIN` command into one long string and execute it

declare @sql    nvarchar(max)

select  @sql    = isnull(@sql, '')
        + 'DROP LOGIN ' + quotename(p.name) + ';' + char(13)
from    #TMP_SP_VALIDATELOGINS l
        inner join sys.server_principals p  on  l.COL_NT_Login  = p.name 

-- Print out to verify
print   @sql

-- unmask to execute
-- exec sp_executesql @sql
```